# Why ``ltablex`` keeps adding vertical space before the ``tabularx`` environment?

Tags: ltablex

Here an extra vertical space is added before the `tabularx` environment (you can see that by comparing it with the same document compiled w/o `ltablex` package and with the `\keepXColumns` line commented out. How do I get rid of that extra space?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext,booktabs,cmap,ltablex,tabularx}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\keepXColumns

\begin{document}

\section*{Random Section}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
\toprule
1 & \blindtext \\
2 & \blindtext \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally `tabularx` is like `tabular` and is an *inline* table set as part of the current line of the paragraph, so has no external spacing.

This package changes them all to be `longtable` essentially that is *display* environments set in vertical mode. So they are never part of the current line, and the space before is the controlled by, for example

```
\setlength\LTpre{3in}
```

You could reduce this, but the layout is still fundamentally different.

(`ltxtable` is a different combination of `tabularx` and `longtable` that doesn't have this feature.)

Comment: I see... but the ``\setlength\LTpre{0pt}`` hack works so thank you!

Comment: What is the difference between ltxtable and ltablex?

Comment: @skan both merge tabularx and longtable but done by different people. Since I wrote one of them, I'm not the person to provide an objective review:-)

Comment: OK, thank you.  I've also read that tabu is newer but if I check its last update was a really long time ago

Comment: @skan tabu has other issues but define "long time ago" my ltxtable package seems to be dated 1995/12/11 which some people might consider to be a long time ago as well:-) tabu is dated 2011/02/26 which seems quite recent to me:-)

Comment: Oh, yeah!!, your package is the grandaddy of the packages :)